# how to sum multiple columns in sql query refrance group

Tags: ms-access

I need to make Group by Agent Name and calculate all amount for each agent using sql query

i have 3 column agent and 3 column amount not 1 column agent and 3 amount that your demo applied column have agent name and 3 column amount 1,2,3 and i mean 6 column that common factor is name and need to calculate amount for each one of them

[image]

This is the Query I have tried So far,

```
SELECT  InternalInvestigation.Agent Name, 
        InternalInvestigation.Amount, 
        InternalInvestigation.[Amount 2], 
        InternalInvestigation.[Amount 3], 
FROM InternalInvestigation
GROUP BY InternalInvestigation.Agent Name, 
         InternalInvestigation.Amount, 
         InternalInvestigation.[Amount 2],
         InternalInvestigation.[Amount 3];
```

This is the table what I'm trying to Sum:

[image: Sample Image]
I need to get data as like the above pic

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Comment: I am sorry, but what kind of a table structure is this? Also, can you please elaborate about what amount do you want to sum?

Comment: i need sum all amount column Amount + amoun2 + amount3 by grouping Agnet name

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

select agents.name, sum(amount1+amount2+amount3) as totalAmount from agents group by agents.name

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below logic-

```
SELECT an agent_name,SUM(amt) total_amount
FROM
(
    SELECT agent_name an,amount amt FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT agent_name_2,amount_2 FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT agent_name_3,amount3 FROM your_table
) A
GROUP BY an
```

Comment: thank ypu for answer but i have error syntax error(missing operator) in quary

Comment: It should work with adjusted table and column name as per your table structure. Can you please provide the query you are trying with?

Comment: i used the same query you are provide me with some changes in my name in table

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you want with the following query :

```
SELECT agent_name, SUM(amount+amount2+amount3) as Total
FROM InternalInvestigation
GROUP BY agent_name;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0e2659a19df0313d49681890c9aa75ae)

Comment: Show me empty result with no calculation

Comment: What do you mean ? This is exactly the expected result you are looking for.

Comment: i applied that in access SQL and result is empty :)

Comment: i have 3 column agent and 3 column amount not 1 column agent and 3 amount that your demo applied column  have agent name and 3 column  amount 1,2,3 and i mean 6 column  that common factor is name and need to calculate amount for each one of them

Comment: Please at least show me a screen of what you are doing (without any change), with exact query, exact set of data and exact table structure. Without more information we can't give you hints.

Comment: You said "i need sum all amount column Amount + amoun2 + amount3 by grouping Agnet name" and in your example above, you didn't use columns agent_name_2 and agent_name_3

Comment: sorry for that but i need to columns agent_name_2 and agent_name_3

Comment: Then please change your question to match what you really want and we will help you